# Filter out mint and burn Transfers from Transfer events (web3.js)

Tags: web3js, events, websocket, event-handling

In [web.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) Library
Is there a way to filter out the Transfers events generated by the mint and burn function
so as to ignore all the Transfer events generated by the mint or burn function.
I know we can filter events by indexed to and from addresses but is there some sort of filter by not address `to: !address` and `from: !address`

so the filter to ignore mint and burn Transfer events can be
`to : !(0x00000...)`
`from: !(0x0000...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot use `!address` in the filter. Instead, you should use the filter function in JavaScript.